# Daemonize process with autostart

Tags: services, process, ruby, background-process

I have simple script written in Ruby.

- I'd like to run as a background task (daemon process or service).
- What is more want to have control over it so that I can start and stop it.
- It will be perfect if process can be started automatically when my VPS restarts.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found perfect solution for that. It requires `upstart` so is far more easier than standard services, `runit` and `systemd`.

Here is more detailed instruction:
http://blog.arkency.com/2014/06/create-run-and-manage-your-background-processes-with-upstart/

And it is something like:

In `/etc/init/my_program_upstart_script.conf`:

```
start on my_event
respawn
exec /home/my_user/my_program/my_program_executable
```

Yes, so simple!

Just run the program with `sudo initctl emit my_event`.

Comment: It's supercool to receive -1 without comment.

Comment: Yep that is very nice tutorial using upstart. But I flag the answer as low quality because its just a link. Could you summarize important steps (or your case as example) here and leave the link as reference.

Comment: @Sneetsher, updated.

Comment: Well done. Sure you don't need a stop event. (so it does not have dependencies). Also you may give it a short name so it possible to use `sudo service myprogram stop/start/..` or `sudo stop/start/.. myprogram`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to create a bash scripts that start/stop your application.
Follow `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as example.

Install you script:

```
    sudo copy yourApplicationCtl /etc/init.d
    sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/yourApplicationCtl
```

In order to start your application at boot of server and stop at shutdown:

```
    sudo update-rc.d yourApplicationCtl defaults
```

If you want to manually start/stop your application:

```
    sudo service yourApplicationCtl start/stop
```

Useful link are: [UbuntuBootupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto), man page of [upgrade-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) and [service](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/service.8.html)

Comment: Quite nice but too complex for single script.